# How to restrict input field from accepting special characters in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, string

I have a input field that should not be blank and should not allow special characters.

I have something like this for validation:

```
if (value === '' || !value.trim()) {
      this.invalidNameFeedback = 'This field can not be blank.';
      return false;
    } else if (!value.match(/[\p{Letter}\p{Mark}]+/gu)) {
      this.invalidNameFeedback = 'This field can not contain special characters.';
      return false;
    }
```

This allows special characters when entered with alphabets or numbers. I dont want allow special characters at all.

Comment: So use a regular expression that only allows letters and numbers. You can find one if you google "regular expression that only allows letters and numbers"

Comment: Yes but I want to support unicode also

Comment: Try `/\W/g` to restrict the non-word character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the whole value to only match a selected character class and use for example `.test()`

```
^[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]+$
```

See the [regex matches](https://regex101.com/r/cjYKze/1).

Example

```
if (value === '' || !value.trim()) {
    this.invalidNameFeedback = 'This field can not be blank.';
    return false;
} else if (!/^[\p{Alphabetic}\p{Mark}\p{Decimal_Number}\p{Connector_Punctuation}\p{Join_Control}]+$/u.test(value)) {
    this.invalidNameFeedback = 'This field can not contain special characters.';
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I works fine but I want to allow spaces also between words. It is considering spaces as invalid character

Comment: I just used \p{Space_Separator} this also along with your answer. Thanks!